# Push Unique Objects to JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I push an object into an specified array that only updates that array? My code pushes an object and updates all arrays, not just the specified one.

**Here is the structure of the data:**

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "cost": "3",
                "item": "Project 1",
                "fiscalyear": "2014",
                "reportmonth": "July"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Here is a sample of the desired, wanted results**:

```
{
    "Project 1": [
        {
            "date": "31-Jul-14",
            "rating": "3"
        },
        {
            "date": "31-Aug-14",
            "rating": "4"
        }
    ],
    "Project 2": [
        {
            "date": "31-Jul-14",
            "rating": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

**This is my attempt:**

```
var results = data.d.results;
var date;

var projectObj = {},
    projectValues = {},
    project = '';
var cost = '',
    costStatus = '';

for (var i = 0, m = results.length; i < m; ++i) {

    project = results[i]['item'];

    if (!projectObj.hasOwnProperty(project)) {
        projectObj[project] = [];
    }

    // use Moment to get and format date
    date = moment(new Date(results[i]['reportmonth'] + ' 1,' + results[i]['fiscalyear'])).endOf('month').format('DD-MMM-YYYY');

    // get cost for each unique project
    costStatus = results[i]['cost'];
    if (costStatus == null || costStatus == 'N/A') {
        cost = 'N/A';
    }
    else {
        cost = costStatus;
    }

    projectValues['rating'] = cost;
    projectValues['date'] = date;

    projectObj[project].push(projectValues);
}
```

**Here is a Fiddle with the undesired, unwanted results:**
https://jsfiddle.net/yh2134jn/4/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `var projectValues = {}` needs to be inside the loop otherwise you'll just keep pushing a reference to the same object into the array.

Comment: And this has nothing whatsoever to do with JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Andys answer is correct. You might also want to try to copy your object before you push it, so you dont push a reference. Like this: `projectObj[project].push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(projectValues)));` (but it would be better practise to do it like Andy said. And if you like my solution, you should make a copy function for `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`

Comment: @Andy -- thanks for the suggestion. I suspected it was something simple.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder -- you're right. I struggled with how to title and ask the question. I'll be more careful when using the JSON tag in the future.

Comment: @InsOp -- I appreciate the advice and the fuller explanation. I'll try that as well.

Answer (score 1):

That is because You do not empty it new iteration. Try this:

```
for (var i = 0, m = results.length; i < m; ++i) {    
    projectValues = {};
    project = results[i]['item'];
    ....
}
```